# Which Chinese Language Package to install for which purpose?

Tags: input-method, ibus

Following a step by step description of how to install the Chinese input method on Linux Mint, the first step is to install Chinese Language Package, unfortunately it was not mentioned which one, searching for a solution online I got even more confused because of the overwhelming information I could not process as a layman. 
Could you explain the differences in usage of the Chinese Language Packages (Picture below)

[image]